# VS Code C/C++ IntelliSense not working with Remote SSH

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My local machine is Windows 10 (VS Code 1.83.1, C/C++ extension 1.18.0).
My remote machine is Red Hat 8 (VS Code 1.81.1, C/C++ extension 1.18.0).
C++ IntelliSense, Outline, and Go To Definition work well when using VS Code locally on Win or over a traditional SSH/X11 session on RH.

But the response time is slow when using RH with traditional SSH/X11, so I setup VS Code Remote SSH.

The connection from Windows to RH works well and the response time is much better scrolling through code.

The problem is that when Remote SSHd into RH the Intellisense, Outline, and Go To Definition features don't work.
When doing the remote and going to the Extensions pane, I see two groupings:

- LOCAL - INSTALLLED
- SSH: [machine-name] - INSTALLED.

Under LOCAL there is C/C++ extension 1.18.0. Under SHH there is C/C++ 1.18.1 (notice the last .1).

In the lower right when I click "{}" it shows three entries:

- IntelliSense: Ready
- [a barrel/database icon] Initializing Workspace (I think this should read Parsing Complete.)
- Code Analysis Mode: Manual

Security on the RH machine is fairly tight, so I had to manually install the C/C++ extension on that box from a vsix file which is how I ended up with 1.18.1 there.

Comment: what do you observe if you install version 1.18.1 on your local machine as well?

Comment: do any of the [existing issue tickets](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aremote) cover what you observe? If not, I suggest that you also raise an issue ticket yourself, giving as much info as you can about how to reproduce the problem. If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.

Comment: @starball Thanks. I had checked existing issues, but had missed the ones you included. Unfortunately still no solution. I did create an [issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/11620) two days ago, but no response yet.
I'll try installing 1.18.1 as you recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was related to security/permissions on the remote machine because the intellisense database file wasn't being created.
The first sean-mcmanus post in this reply helped lead to a solution:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6958

I ended up creating a c_cpp_properties.json in my workspace and included the "browse" section below. This causes the intellisense db file to be created in the workspace area where security permissions are less strict. The IntelliSense, Outline, and Go To Definition features all work fine now.

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c99",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++98",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/vc.db"
        }
    }
],
"version": 4  
}
```